# XUnit Net Core Web API Integration Test: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Tags: integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

Just trying to build an Integration Test project for a NET Core Web API.
So I've followed a few examples, including this one (https://dotnetcorecentral.com/blog/asp-net-core-web-api-integration-testing-with-xunit/) and naturally, I run into issues.  When I run the simple GET test I get an exception:
"System.InvalidOperationException : The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());`, you need to manually configure the `appsettings.json` path like

```
var server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                    .UseContentRoot(@"D:\Edward\SourceCode\AspNetCore\Tests\IntegrationTestMVC") 
                    // This is the path for project which needs to be test
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    );
```

For a convenience way, I would suggest you try [Basic tests with the default WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory).

> The WebApplicationFactory constructor infers the app content root path by searching for a WebApplicationFactoryContentRootAttribute on the assembly containing the integration tests with a key equal to the TEntryPoint assembly System.Reflection.Assembly.FullName. In case an attribute with the correct key isn't found, WebApplicationFactory falls back to searching for a solution file (*.sln) and appends the TEntryPoint assembly name to the solution directory. The app root directory (the content root path) is used to discover views and content files.

Reference:[How the test infrastructure infers the app content root path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-the-test-infrastructure-infers-the-app-content-root-path)

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track along with the discussion here: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1191   I used WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder() and .UseContentRoot("approjectpath") and it seems to be using the appsettings.json for the API project now, so I am able to test the true infrastructure (API/EF core/Database)

Answer (score 0):

I had to override `CreateHostBuilder` in my derived `WebApplicationFactory` in order to add the configuration for the connection string (since it was read from user secrets).

```cs
    public class CustomApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Sedab.MemberAuth.Startup>
    {
        protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
        {
            var initialData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection", "test")
            };

            return base.CreateHostBuilder().ConfigureHostConfiguration(config => config.AddInMemoryCollection(initialData));
        }
    }
```